# Word/phrase for changing applicability of something

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests

What's the word/phrase to indicate that applicability of something has been changed. For example in a given scenario, how to announce " enjoy tool "A" in its new application" in the form of "---- of tool "A"".

Comment: You mean an -"update"?

Comment: @Josh61, No! For example, using a knife for fixing a car! It emphasizes on innovation, novel perspective to turn something useful  into another useful thing. Of course, there are strong theoretical reasons that support the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Consider ***reimagine***.

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reimagine) defines it as:

> to imagine again or anew; especially :  to form a new conception of

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reimagine) suggests a similar meaning

> To imagine or conceive something in a new way

**Usage:**

> Presenting the ***reimagined*** version of Tool A
>
> A complete ***reimagination*** of ToolA

Answer (score 1):

How about ***retool***?

> 1. To fit out (a factory, for example) with a new set of machinery and tools for making a different product.
> 2. (*Chiefly AmEng*) To revise and reorganize, especially for the purpose of updating or improving. [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/retool)
>
> *Enjoy "A" in its [retooled application](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22home+supplies%22&biw=1024&bih=672&prmd=misvn&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGqcG60ZLLAhWJExoKHdidDnIQ_AUIBSgA&dpr=2#q=%22retooled+application%22).*

Answer (score 0):

If you change applicability of something, it usually improves or upgrades the applicability.

You could consider using "**upgraded** version". To [*upgrade*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/upgrade?q=upgraded) means:

> Raise (something) to a higher standard, in particular improve
>   (equipment or machinery) by adding or replacing components

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Comment: I don't think this fits the bill

Comment: @NVZ Can you elaborate? The question doesn't have anything to support your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [**Upcycle**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/upcycle)

> *I upcycled a stained tablecloth into curtains.*

It basically means to reuse (discarded objects or material) in such a way as to create a product of higher quality or value than the original.

Also see: [Upcycling vs Recycling.](http://www.evereone.com/blogs/news/18784767-recycling-versus-upcycling-put-simply)There's a subtle difference.

These words may be found useful, although not perfectly - **repurposing, re-engineering, redoing, remodeling, renovating, revising, re-implementing.**

Answer (score 0):

*Off label use* is a widely understood humorous euphemism.

There are some others used by tradesmen that have escaped the narrow confines of their trade.

"Birmingham screwdriver" for a hammer, and by extension, any abusive tool misuse borne of necessity or laziness.

When you hold on to a found object, utensil, or part be cause it just happens to perform some odd job perfectly, it becomes "special tool #39" (or some other number). There is a folk etymology suggesting this came from an automotive tool kit that came with an empty slot.